# Could I put “respectively” in this position?

Tags: word-usage

There are a tall tree and a short flower. Could I say “there are respectively a tall and a short tree and flower”

Comment: @Astralbee I mean, whether “respectively” is related to adjectives or nouns, so there’s a slight difference.

Comment: The principle is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> “Respectively” is an adverb meaning “in the order mentioned.” We use it when we want to emphasize the relationships between two pairs or items in two parallel lists (i.e., two lists that contain the same number of items).

*Source: https://getproofed.com/writing-tips/use-respectively-sentence/*

When building a sentence with *respectively*, it can be helpful to think of two or more parallel sentences, and then combine them.

> The **tree** is **tall**.
>
> The *flower* is *short*.
>
> The **tree** and the *flower* are **tall** and *short*, respectively.

> **Alice** ate **two** slices of pizza.
>
> *John* ate *five* slices of pizza.
>
> **Alice** and *John* ate **two** and *five* slices of pizza, respectively.

> **I** was born in **December**.
>
> *My brother* was born in *June*.
>
> ***My sister*** was born in ***October***.
>
> *My brother*, ***my sister*** and **I** were born in *June*, ***October*** and **December**, respectively.

The trouble with your example phrase ("a tall and a short tree and flower") is that the parts are in the wrong order. To use "respectively" correctly, the elements in the second list should describe, modify, or give more information about the elements in the first list. You have put the list of adjectives *before* the list of nouns that the adjectives describe, which is backwards.

Comment: I turned it into the sentence.

Comment: @user0203 Please do not change your original question in response to my answer. It is against site policy to change questions once asked, except to make them clearer. When the question is different, all the good answers become bad ones!

Comment: @user0203 I have edited my answer. The new answer should fit both the edited version of your question and the original version.

Answer (score 1):

In academic writing, one would typically use "The tree and flower are respectively tall and short." or "The tree and flower are tall and short, respectively." (Source: internal style guide for journal groups such as Elsevier and Springer–Nature.)